How to mask certain input characters which are binded to input field in angular
I am getting secret key as a response from my server side I want to bind that secret key to my input in secret key i have special characters and string of length 8. I want to disable the fields with character so user cannot change it and want to change the fields with special characters with user input value
I tried binding my server response with my input field but no luck

There are a couple things missing from your post. What exact version of Angular are you using? If its anything v2 or higher, you need to remove the angularjs tag. Also, if you are trying to bind data to an input, that is already well documented for every javascript framework. You also say you tried but don't specify what you actually tried.
